# Keeping hover state of menu button when using sub-menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have made a CSS dropdown menu and when you hover over the main menu button it changes the background image using the `hover` state.

However if the person navigates to the below dropdown selections the main menu button they are currently under naturally loses it's hover state. I have used `Javascript` in the past to change the class so it keeps the same background image, but was wondering is there a way to do it without Javascript?

HTML:

```
<div class="navWrapper">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="about">
                    <a href="about_us/">About Us</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="">option 1</a></li>
                    </ul>                        
                </li>
                <!-- About Ends -->
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="trademark"><a href="freetrademarksearch/">Free Trademark Search</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="services">
                    <a href="services/">Services</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="">option 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">option 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Sub Ends -->
                </li>
                <!-- Services Ends -->
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="testimonials"><a href="testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="more">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">More Information</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="">option 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">option 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Sub Ends -->
                </li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>                 
            </ul>
            <div class="contentClear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Nav Ends -->
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav Wrapper Ends -->
```

CSS:

```
#header .navWrapper {
    width: 1004px;
}

#header .navWrapper .left {
    float: left;
    width: 4px;
    min-width: 4px;
    height: 47px;
    min-height: 47px;
    background: url('../images/nav-left-bg.png') left top no-repeat;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav {
    float: left;
    width: 994px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0d0b4;
    border-left: 1px solid #e0d0b4;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0d0b4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8dcc8;
    background: url('../images/nav-button-bg.png') left top repeat-x;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav ul {
    margin: 0 1px;
    display: block;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    font-family: OpenSansBold, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 2.9;
    text-align: center;
    color: #646464;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li.spacer {
    width: 2px;
    min-width: 2px;
    height: 45px;
    min-height: 45px;
    background: url('../images/nav-button-spacer-bg.png') left top no-repeat;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li a,
#header .navWrapper .nav li a:visited
{
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #646464;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li a:hover,
#header .navWrapper .nav li a:active,
#header .navWrapper .nav li a:focus
{
    color: #fff;
    background: url('../images/nav-button-bg.png') left bottom repeat-x;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li.home {
    max-width: 86px;
    text-indent: -1px;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: -1px;
    top: 45px;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li:hover > ul.sub {
    display: block;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: OpenSansSemibold, Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2.3;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f4771d;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;    
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a,
#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a
{
    color: #fff;
    height: auto;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a:hover,
#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a:focus,
#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a:active
{
    background: #d66627;
}

#header .navWrapper .right {
    float: right;
    width: 4px;
    min-width: 4px;
    height: 47px;
    min-height: 47px;    
    background: url('../images/nav-right-bg.png') left top no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: pls post code you are using or make a jsfiddle. the drop-down has to be a child element of your main menu item to have this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
#header .navWrapper .nav li a:hover,
```

with

```
#header .navWrapper .nav li:hover a,
```

This is, because your sub menu is a child of the `li` element and not the `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the background image for hover states over the parent list item, not the link itself.

```
/* instead of your */
#header .navWrapper .nav li a:hover

/* try */
#header .navWrapper .nav li:hover a
```